# How can I speed up my Rails DelayedJobs time to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku, delayed-job

I am using Rails / Delayed Jobs, with Rails 4.1 on Heroku. I've noticed that my jobs take anywhere from 1 second to 10 seconds to actually start. Once they start, they run pretty fast.

How can I speed that up?

I am calling them with my_thing.delay.run!

I do have some other ongoing jobs, but there's not that many of them, so it doesn't seem like that would be the cause. It just seems like a lagginess in how often it checks to run jobs.

Comment: I believe delayed job using polling to find jobs to run. Perhaps there is configuration for the poll interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to configure `Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay` which is hinted at in the delayed job [README](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details). If delayed job can't find a job then it sleeps for this many seconds before looking again. The default sleep is for 5 seconds.

So, you might set the following in `config/initializers/delayed_job.rb` to only sleep for 2 seconds between queries for pending jobs.

```
Delayed::Worker.sleep_delay = 2
```

Obviously the trade-off is the more frequent polling for jobs when nothing is going on.

Also, if you're not wedded to delayed job then you might find [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or particularly [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) would probably process your jobs quicker than delayed job.